# Symfony 3 form + Aurelia

Tags: aurelia, symfony

So i've playing around with building a web app in Symfony 3, using a form type and rendering the form on the page. I am starting to Aurelia, and am trying to render a Symfony form on the page via an Aurelia custom element, and then post the form back to symfony. I've gotten to the point of validating the form upon submit, but it never validates. Can someone please look over the below code and see if i'm missing something somewhere?

Form type:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\MoneyType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\NumberType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\IntegerType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CheckboxType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use AppBundle\Service\PayeeService;

class PayeeType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', TextType::class)
            ->add('category', ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices' => [
                    'Uncategorized' => PayeeService::CATEGORY_UNCATEGORIZED,
                    'Installment Loan' => PayeeService::CATEGORY_INSTALLMENT_LOAN,
                    'Credit Card' => PayeeService::CATEGORY_CREDIT_CARD,
                    'Utility' => PayeeService::CATEGORY_UTILITY,
                    'Mortgage' => PayeeService::CATEGORY_MORTGAGE,
                    'Entertainment' => PayeeService::CATEGORY_ENTERTAINMENT
                ],
                'choices_as_values' => true
                ])
            ->add('amount', MoneyType::class, ['currency' => 'USD', 'grouping' => true])
            ->add('frequency', ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices' => [
                    'Recurring' => PayeeService::FREQUENCY_RECURRING,
                    'One-time' => PayeeService::FREQUENCY_ONETIME
                ],
                'choices_as_values' => true
                ])
            ->add('method', ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices' => [
                    'ACH' => PayeeService::PAY_METHOD_ACH,
                    'Check' => PayeeService::PAY_METHOD_CHECK
                ],
                'choices_as_values' => true
                ])
            ->add('dateLastPaid', DateType::class)
            ->add('dueDate', DateType::class)
            ->add('gracePeriod', IntegerType::class)
            ->add('balance', MoneyType::class, ['currency' => 'USD', 'grouping' => true])
            ->add('active', CheckboxType::class, ['label' => 'Active', 'data' => true])
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, ['label' => 'Save Payee'])
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Payee'
        ));
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;

class FormController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/_form/entity/{entity}", name="new_entity_form")
     * @Method("GET")
     */
    public function getFormForNewEntity(Request $request)
    {
        $rawName = $request->get('entity');
        $content = $request->getContent();
        $data = json_decode($content, true);
        $formName = strtolower($rawName) . "_form";
        $submitFunction = $data['submitFunction'];
        $entityName = "AppBundle\Entity\\" . $rawName;
        $entity = new $entityName();
        $form = $this->createForm("\AppBundle\Form\\{$rawName}Type", $entity);
        return $this->render('form/form.html.twig', [
            'name' => $formName,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'submitFunction' => $submitFunction]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/_form/entity/{entity}", name="new_entity_create")
     * @Method("POST")
     */
    public function saveFormForNewEntity(Request $request)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $rawName = $request->get('entity');
        $entityName = "AppBundle\Entity\\" . $rawName;
        $entity = new $entityName();
        $form = $this->createForm("\AppBundle\Form\\{$rawName}Type", $entity);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em->persist($entity);
            $em->flush();
            return new JsonResponse(['result' => true]);
        } elseif ($form->isEmpty()) {
            return new JsonResponse(['result' => false, 'errors' => 'form empty']);
        } else {
            return new JsonResponse(['result' => false, 'errors' => iterator_to_array($form->getErrors(true))]);
        }
    }
}
```

Form twig:

```
{{ form_start(form, {'attr': {'id':name, 'role':'form', 'submit.delegate':submitFunction}}) }}
{{ form_widget(form) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Aurelia component js:

```
import {InlineViewStrategy} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {customElement, bindable, inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import $ from 'jquery';
import {HttpClient} from 'aurelia-http-client';
import 'fetch';

@customElement('symfony-form')
@inject(Element)
export class SymfonyForm {

    @bindable entity;

    constructor(element) {
        this.content = '';
        this.http = new HttpClient();
        this.http.configure(config => {
          config
            .withBaseUrl('http://localhost:8000/');
        });


        this.element = element;
    }

    bind(binding, override) {
        return this.http.get('_form/entity/' + this.entity, {'submitFunction': 'submit()'})
        //.then(response => response.html())
        .then(response => {
            this.content = response.response;
        });
    }

    submit() {
        // application/x-www-form-urlencoded
        this.http.createRequest('_form/entity/' + this.entity)
            .withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
            .asPost()
            .withContent($(this.element).find('form').serialize())
            .send()
            .then(response => {
                alert(response.response);
            });
        //alert('submitted ' + this.entity);
        // return this.http.post('_form/entity/' + this.entity, $(this.element).find('form').serialize())
        // .then(response => {
        //     alert(response.response);
        // });
    }
}
```

aurelia component view:

```
<template>
    <form role="form" submit.delegate="submit()">
        <div innerHTML.bind="content"></div>
    </form>
</template>
```

aurelia page:

```
<template>
    <require from="form"></require>
  <section class="au-animate">
    <h2>${heading}</h2>
    <form role="form" submit.delegate="submit()">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="fn">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" value.bind="firstName" class="form-control" id="fn" placeholder="first name">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="ln">Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" value.bind="lastName" class="form-control" id="ln" placeholder="last name">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Full Name</label>
        <p class="help-block">${fullName | upper}</p>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <symfony-form entity="Payee"></symfony-form>
  </section>
</template>
```

Comment: Why don't you want to have a single-page application on Aurelia for frontend and use Symfony only as an API for the backend?

Comment: I was wondering the same thing. Also I'm not sure if you're asking about the form validation in symfony or in the js?

Comment: @AlexanderM. I am planning to have a SPA for the front-end, but I was hoping to use my existing symfony forms to get some validation and CRUD operations for free.

Comment: @tftd I am asking about the validation in symfony. the $form->isValid() always returns false, and the $form->getErrors() call returns nothing.

Comment: I see. Well the problem here is you're using Aurelia to render the form template. If you read the documentation [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#rendering-the-form), you'll see you need to use `{{ form_start(form) }}{{ form_end(form) }}` which includes some hidden [CSFR](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#forms-csrf) fields. You can explicitly render the CSFR field with `{{ form_widget(form._token) }}`. I guess that's what makes your form fail the validation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on SPAs, or JS frameworks, but from what I can see the problem is the lack of a CSFR field with the correct token and also that I don't believe your inputs are named correctly for symphony to read them correctly (I may have missed where this is handled so apologies if so). You need to have the input name formatted as below:

```
<input type="text" name="formname[formfield]" />
```

So for example I believe you need your name field to be:

```
<input type="text" name="payeetype[name]" />
```